# How to sum conditional expression with argument repeated in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Queryset. How can I sum 'output' that have jam=('16-17','17-18','18-19')

```py
develop_queryset = InputCutSew.objects.filter(publish='2019-07-30').exclude(cell_name__isnull=True).exclude(cell_name__exact='').order_by('cell_name', 'jam').values('cell_name','model','jam').annotate\
            (total_output_ot=Sum(Case(When(jam='16-17', jam='17-18', jam='18-19', then='output')))).exclude(total_output_ot__isnull=True)
```

result: 
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

I already try this but still output still separate not sum

```py
.annotate(total_output_ot=Sum(Case(
                                      When(jam='16-17', then='output'),
                                      When(jam='17-18', then='output'),
                                      When(jam='18-19', then='output'),))).exclude(total_output_ot__isnull=True)
<QuerySet [{'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '16-17', 'total_output_ot': 10}, {'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '16-17', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '17-18', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '17-18', 'total_output_ot': 10}, {'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '18-19', 'total_output_ot': 10}, {'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '18-19', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '16-17', 'total_output_ot': 10}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '16-17', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '17-18', 'total_output_ot': 10}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '17-18', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '18-19', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '18-19', 'total_output_ot': 10}]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should do it like this:

```
develop_queryset = InputCutSew.objects.filter(publish='2019-07-30').exclude(cell_name__isnull=True).exclude(cell_name__exact='').order_by('cell_name', 'jam').values('cell_name','model','jam').annotate(
    total_output_ot=Case(
        When(jam='16-17', then=Value(17)),
        When(jam='17-18', then=Value(18)),
        When(jam='18-19', then=Value(19)),
    ), output_field=IntegerField()
).exclude(total_output_ot__isnull=True)


sum_of_total_output_ot = develop_queryset.aggregate(val = Sum('total_output_ot')).get('val')
```

Comment: .annotate(total_output_ot=Sum(Case(
                                      When(jam='16-17', then='output'),
                                      When(jam='17-18', then='output'),
                                      When(jam='18-19', then='output'),))).exclude(total_output_ot__isnull=True)

Comment: I already try but output still separate <QuerySet [{'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '16-17', 'total_output_ot': 10}, {'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '16-17', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '17-18', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '17-18', 'total_output_ot': 10}, {'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '18-19', 'total_output_ot': 10}, {'cell_name': '13a', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '18-19', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model':

Comment: 'superstar', 'jam': '16-17', 'total_output_ot': 10}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '16-17', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '17-18', 'total_output_ot': 10}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '17-18', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'questar flow', 'jam': '18-19', 'total_output_ot': 20}, {'cell_name': '13b', 'model': 'superstar', 'jam': '18-19', 'total_output_ot': 10}]>

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding your comments. Can you please update the question with what is not working?

Comment: For Sum, you need to use aggregate in this case. Please see the updated answer